# BIRT : Sort a Table based on Multiple Columns

Tags: birt

I have a BIRT report generated from a JAVA POJO data source.

```
 Interface | column1 | column2 |
+----------+---------+---------+
|          |         |         |
```

I want to sort the rows of the Table given above, based on the sum of 2 columns column1 and column2
And then display the top 10 rows.

In the Sorting Tab, I've used for the expression: row["column1"]+row["column2"] and in the Filters Tab, I've put the expression row["column1"]+row["column2"], Operator as Top n and Value1 as 10.
But I'm not getting the desired result

Comment: Show us what you've already tried.

Comment: In the Sorting Tab, I've used for the expression:  row["column1"]+row["column2"] and in the Filters Tab, I've put the expression row["column1"]+row["column2"], Operator as Top n and Value1 as 10

Comment: Wee need a full code snippet with all necessary informations (not more) in it so we can reproduce this scenario. Edit your post.

Comment: Yes. It is Working Now.

I've created a new binding with the expression row["column1"]+row["column2"] and sorted based on the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am posting this Answer so that it might be useful to a lot of BIRT beginners**

1. Create a new Column Binding with the Expression : ( row["column1"]+row["column2"] )
2. Sort the Table based on the binding.